# Trouble Adding grades using Google Classroom API and Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

I am unable to change grades using the Google Classroom API. When I run the code below, lines 2 and 3 run fine. However, line 4 fails with the following message: @ProjectPermissionDenied The Developer Console project is not permitted to make this request.

```
1)  var studentSubmission = {'assignedGrade':'1'};
2)  var studentSubmissions = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.StudentSubmissions.list(courseId, courseWorkId, {userId:'studentEmail@apps.matsuk12.us'});
3)  var studentAssignmentId = studentSubmissions['studentSubmissions'][0].id;
4)  Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.StudentSubmissions.patch(studentSubmission, courseId, courseWorkId, studentAssignmentId,{'updateMask':'assignedGrade'});
```

When I go to Project Properties and look at the scopes, here is what I see:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.emails
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.photos
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
```

I am trying to access my own Google Classroom using a container bound script (spreadsheet). Seems like if I have access to the assignments, I should have access to add a grade. Not sure why I can't add the grade. Is there anything I can do to get this code working? The end goal is to be able to grade assignments using a form (not a google form) and have the score automatically pushed to Google Classroom.

I saw a related post that mentions a solution, but it is not clear how to implement it: [Permission denied using Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.StudentSubmissions.list(4140802199, 4801051201);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42799045/permission-denied-using-classroom-courses-coursework-studentsubmissions-list414)

I also see a related bug report here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67748271 (I'm not sure though if this really is a bug, or if this is just how the Google Classroom API works, or if I'm just doing something wrong)

Answer (score 0):

From the posts you linked someone posted this code:

```
function createCoursework (id) {
 Classroom.Courses.CourseWork
  .create(id, { 
// doesn't work but triggers permissions correctly "courseId": id, "title": 'foo', "description": 'desc', }); 
}
```

Essentially you need to put this code somewhere in your projects code. Then, using the, Run menu, execute that function. It won't do anything, but it will initialize the authorization request from google; by means of a popup. After that you should be good to delete that function and use that scope.

Comment: I tried running the code you referenced. I had to modify it to get it to actually run. Once it did run, no authorization request was initialized. From what I can tell, I have the scope already (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students). Which one do you think I am missing? After specifying one of my course Ids, here's what I ran: Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.create({"title": 'foo', "description": 'desc',"workType":'ASSIGNMENT'}, courseId)